# How to step back with 2 commits in GitExtension?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am working on some branch, let's say branch "A". And I am using GitExtension. I commited something on that branch. Then after some time I again commited something. And now I should make patch file with both this commits, but when I format patch, it makes patch file just from last commit. How could revert this 2 commits and then make a patch from that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select both commits on the grid at the bottom.
GitExtensions will create a patch for each selected commit.

[image]